# Weird error message on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

After running I am able to see the app, but when I restart the emulator and click the app, its just showing App isn't installed. what could be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

check your android AndroidManifest.xml file carefully, there may be something wrong like you have given the wrong permission or added one permission twice. If not then add this user permission to your file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also check if you have specified the launcher correctly in menifest file

Comment: This is an internal app, i will specify the install location as internal only and see what happens. anyways thank you..